# dateformat mask to md-datepicker in angular material 2

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular-material2

How to add a dateformat mask to md-datepicker ?

If I specify date format as `DD/MM/YYYY` , then once user start to type inside datepicker, user will be able to insert

- `DD` upto `31`
- `MM` upto `12`
- `YYYY` upto `9999` with separate `/`

so final result like following

A **correct date** with **`__/__/____`** mask.

currently once I try to insert this like following, but its not applying

```
<md-form-field>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" ui-mask="XX.XX.XXXX">
  <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
  <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
</md-form-field>
```

SO I tried following approaches, none of this work

```
ui-mask="XX.XX.XXXX"

os-mask="3?9/19/9999"

MASK="DD/MM/YYYY"
```

[**Plunkr Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Orjed6WqYRku0GyuwHSC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any masking functionality in angular material2 yet.
You could use the text-mask library (https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask) but the angular version won't work with material2 because angular doesn't allow input fields to have more than one ValueAcessor.

A work around is to use the vanilla version of text-mask:

1 - Import the library in your component

```
import * as textMask from "vanilla-text-mask/dist/vanillaTextMask.js";
```

2 - Add your mask in the component and init your input (don't forget to import AfterViewInit and implement it to your component)

```
  mask = [ /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/];
  maskedInputController;

  @ViewChild("input", { read: ViewContainerRef }) public input;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.maskedInputController = textMask.maskInput({
        inputElement: this.input.element.nativeElement,
        mask: this.mask
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.maskedInputController.destroy();
  }
```

3 - in your template, make sure the input element has an #input attribute

```
<mat-form-field class="input">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" #input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```